# Desire2Learn course info in SOAP and Valence APIs

Tags: desire2learn

In Desire2Learn, does the ID and name/description for a given course have the same values in both the SOAP and the Valence APIs?  Also, is there a Valence API call for retrieving the list of courses available to the user?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the suggested calls part of your question: You can get a list of enrollments (both courses and departments and any other structures your school has) using the [myenrollments call](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-enrollments-myenrollments-)

To filter by org unit type you can first [retrieve the types](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-outypes-)

Comment: Is there a similar Valence API call to retrieve the list of courses for a specific user ID?

Comment: If a course is a particular "org unit type", how do you unambiguously identify which org unit type maps to course, in order to filter the list of enrollments so that only courses are returned?

Comment: @user1382547 The course offering org unit type ID is a built-in (3, I believe), so you should be able to filter the myenrollments call on that org unit type to get the list of all the student's _current_ enrollments.